# sshfs in fstab not run in CentOS Stream 8

Tags: centos, mount, sshfs

I added below statement in /etc/fstab.

```
root@IP:/SERVER_DIR /LOCAL_MOUNT_DIR fuse.sshfs nonempty,allow_other 0 0
```

But when I boot-up, LOCAL_MOUNT_DIR does not mounted.

Is it right sentence to mount?

OS is CentOS Stream 8